# Search large string for multiple instances if smaller string in r

Tags: r

In R, I have taken a JSON format of test results and converted them to a data frame of 14 variables and 1101 entries. In this test, the user must select squares in a particular order for a correct score. Under one variable, "input," the values are long strings with info on which square was selected and the time it took to select the square.
Ex:

```
"[{\"selectedSquare\":\"1\",\"tapTime\":\"00:00:00:06\"}, 
{\"selectedSquare\":\"0\",\"tapTime\":\"00:00:01:02\"}, 
{\"selectedSquare\":\"3\",\"tapTime\":\"00:00:02:00\"}, 
{\"selectedSquare\":\"2\",\"tapTime\":\"00:00:02:07\"}]"
```

Some entries have more than others, some have none.

I need to search each entry for the square a student selected, and output the order into a new column. Using the example above:
1,0,3,2

I have tried to access each entry individually to test functions on using `df$input[1]`, but it returns a factor with 219 levels. I cannot find a way to only access the relevant piece of the input entry.

Comment: I don't see `input` in your sample data ... but if I'm right, then: you should not be trying to parse json within a field, consider *nesting* a frame within a cell with `input$col <- lapply(input$col, jsonlite::fromJSON)`. It takes some deliberate filtering for frame-within-a-frame, but it might be more intuitive to you to develop a function that looks at just one of these inner-frames, and then `lapply` that function on a whole column at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an appropriate regular expression. Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
pattern <- "(?<=\")\\d(?=\")" ## regular expression with look arounds
df$new.col <- sapply(df$input, function(x) {str_extract_all(x, pattern)[[1]] %>% paste(collapse = ",")})
```

Comment: Please consider loading only specific packages you need for the answer. In this case, I believe it's `dplyr` and `stringr`. Not everybody has the whole meta-package `tidyverse` installed, and it might be nice for follow-on askers to know precisely which of the tidy packages they need to implement your answer.

Comment: And an alternative (which adds a package ...), tidy-leaning coders might prefer `purrr::map*` functions to `sapply`, et al.

Comment: @r2evans: code edited. Of course, you are right about the `tidyverse` ecosystem. Thanks for the comment. I will be more careful here.